# Can I only select the values if it is not null?

Tags: postgresql, null

I've got values stored in variables that I only want inserted if it doesn't return null - possible to do this with SQL?  I've tried the below:

```
SELECT concat_ws(A, B, C, D, E) is not null;
```

So I think it's still returning (A, null, C, D, null) into variable2 where ideally I'd like it just to return (A, C, D) into variable2 instead.  (Have also tried with concat, coalesce).  Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*I only want inserted*"? Can you post your complete query, please? Also it's unclear how you "*got values stored in variables*" or how it's "*returning [something] into variable2*"

Comment: Your code already works as expected. See the [`concat_ws` documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html): "*The first argument is used as the separator string, and should not be NULL. Other **NULL arguments are ignored**.*"

Comment: all good, it was resolved below - I've marked Mark's answer as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know about the selection into variables, but this should do what you ask if A through E are columns:

```
select array_to_string(array_remove(array[a, b, c, d, e], null), ',') as variable1
  from testme;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=1a7f345877cb9f915c559659d16a3cc7)*